# How do I use curl with urls that contain brackets characters?

Tags: curl

I'm having some trouble using curl for any URLs which contain square brackets.

For example:

```
$ curl 'http://example.org/?param[0]=true'
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 27
```

How do I properly escape the square brackets so that curl will issue the request?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It turns out that curl is trying to interpret the square brackets as a globbing pattern.

Luckily there is a curl option to turn the globbing behavior off:

```
$ curl -g 'http://example.org/?param[0]=true'
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also escape square brackets with backslashes :

```
$ curl 'http://example.org/?param\[0\]=true'
```